# Poll MySQL DB in Socket IO & Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am attempting to poll a MySQL DB by iterating every 2 seconds and retrieving all records created less than 2 seconds ago.

If I use `setInterval` it seems to occasionally miss a record. If I use `setTimeout` it only fetches the first iteration.

How can I fetch the data more reliably to include all data?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    authorize (socket, function(shop_id) {
        setInterval(function() {
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = " + connection.escape(shop_id) +
            " AND `created` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 SECOND)";
            var query = connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err == null) {
                    console.log (rows);
                    socket.emit('newData', rows);
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is not designed to be pulled every 2 seconds. This is not a godo system architecture and you will experience more issues later on, definitely in regards to scalability.

setInterval is not precise and does not guarantee it will sleep for absolute 2000 ms, it may sleep for 2001, 2200, or even 50 hours.

To resolve this, store the most recent `created` that your NodeJS script fetched in a variable, and fetch all rows that are created AFTER your last received `created`. This will get every single record and won't miss records.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {


 authorize (socket, function(shop_id) {
        setInterval(function() {
            var lastCreated = toMySQLDate(new Date());
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = " + connection.escape(shop_id) +
            " AND `created` > " + lastCreated + " ORDER BY `created` DESC";
            var query = connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err == null) {
                    if (rows.length) {
                        lastCreated = toMySQLDate(rows[0].created);
                    }
                    console.log (rows);
                    socket.emit('newData', rows);
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
     });
});

function toMySQLDate(date) {
    return date.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
}
```

Comment: `toMySQLDate()` also needs to be used where `lastCreated` is updated. It won't let me edit the code example. Also typo in SQL `=` should be `+`

Comment: The stats data is not necessarily related to other tables in the database. What would be a better choice of data store for frequent polling with regards to scaling?